# Почему не работают мои запросы sql в qt

Tags: c++, sql, qt, qt5

Вот обычный код подкл. к бд, простой запрос. Ошибки при подкл к бд нет. Зато при запросе ошибка getLastError() показывает

> QSqlError("1", "Unable to execute statement", "no such table:
>   pillow3")

как нету когда таблица точно есть. Бд sql lite созлана отдельно от qt в проге, пароли, юзер от фонаря.

```
bool Sql::createConnection()
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName(nameDb);
    db.setUserName(nameUser);
    db.setHostName(nameHost);
    db.setPassword("password");
    if (!db.open()) {
        qDebug() << "Cannot open database:" << db.lastError();
        return false; // сюда не попадает
    }
    query = new QSqlQuery(db);

   if (!query->exec("SELECT _id FROM "+nameTbl+" ORDER BY _id DESC LIMIT 1")) {
       qDebug() << "Select error 1"; //попадает сюды

      // return false;
   }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `Почему не работают мои запросы sql в qt` -> `no such table: pillow3`

Comment: *как нету когда таблица точно есть* Извините, но словам сервера доверия больше. Проверьте ещё раз, есть ли таблица с именно таким именем, и есть ли у пользователя права на выборку из неё.

Comment: Я в проге sql делаю копирую запрос из debug qtcreator запрос проходит все норм. Только qt не кидает ошибку

Comment: Все я решил вопрос я в назв бд ошибку сделал, счас поправлю, он новую бд создавал и ошибки при подкл не находил.

Comment: На будущее имейте в виду, что когда вы пытаетесь подключиться к базе данных sqlite，а файла не существует, драйвер создаст новую пустую базу данных. Стоит всегда проверять, где именно драйвер будет искать файл с базой данных.